# Lib to display OpenGL video in PyQt?

Tags: video, library, python

I know that a classic way of displaying OpenGL elements inside (Py)**Qt** is to override the `QGLWidget.paint()` method to make direct OpenGL calls. However, does anyone know of a **lib I could use to avoid making direct calls to OpenGL**? Something that would, for example, load an image or video frame to a textured triangle strip in a single call? Or any kind of OpenGl video lib that I could integrate with PyQt?

My final goal is to display OpenGL video inside a PyQt window. Thank you!